# Remove 'menu' on Android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

Im making one application Android 2.3.3 compatible.
All my activities have one bottom menu:

I've tried many things, but I can't hide this menu.
Does anyone know how to hide it?

If I override the 'onCreateOptionsMenu' method I can add more options, but it was all that I got.

The menu appears at the bottom as you can see in the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `targetSdkVersion` to be 14 or higher. Since you are still using the legacy Eclipse environment, that would be the `android:targetSdkVersion` attribute in you manifest.